# Gnome session fails to start on OpenIndiana

Tags: gnome, opensolaris, openindiana

After upgrading from OpenSolaris to OpenIndiana GNOME fails on start.
Cleaning up and recreating profiles had no effect.
Running with --debug option has not helped to recognize the problem

Answer (score 0):

Search by gnome debug traces led to [this](http://openindiana-discuss.openindiana.narkive.com/JRMuZmPe/gnome-session-start-problem-gnome-panel-not-visible) page which gave a hint - possible problems with mixer_app. Indeed

`ps xau | grep mixer`

has shown number of /usr/lib/mixer_app processes running.

There were no instructions  on the surface on proper way of disabling this mixer panel. So I just did

`chmod a-x  /usr/lib/mixer_applet2`

GNOME has complained first time and suggested to remove the panel.